# Updating a folder dynamically in a client-server architecture

Tags: c, windows, file, client-server, directory

I am working on a project wherein a client can access multiple folders on server for read/write operations. However, when the server node adds a file or deletes a file from any of the folders, i want to update that particular folder on client machine dynamically for the changes. Also i can't program anything for the server machine. One solution that i thought of is as soon as the user on client machine accessed a folder, a program checks for the updates made to that folder on the server machine but i dont know whether it is possible or not. The client machine is a windows machine while the server is Linux.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/fs_event.html) to watch for filesystem events.

You'd need a mechanism to push those events to your clients. You could use websockets with the [wslay](https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/wslay) library. You'd then be able to server push the files as they are modified on your server.

Comment: I dont have permission to code for the server machine. I can code only for the client machine.

Comment: Then unless the server exposes events that occur in its API, you cannot. You could put a tcp reverse proxy in front of your server to see what are the calls made to the API and deduce the events from that.